# Sending data from JavaScript to C++, byte values over 127 are replaced with "replacement character"

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, utf-8, zeromq

I'm trying to send buffers of data from a JavaScript application to a C++ application via ZeroMQ (C++ and npm zeromq). If the buffer contains a byte that is > 127, then the byte of data is replaced with 3 bytes:

`\xEF\xBF\xBD`

Research shows me that this the UTF-8 value for the Unicode replacement character (`U+FFFD`).

This doesn't seem to happen anywhere in JavaScript before calling the ZeroMQ `send` function and the data is already corrupted by the time I can receive it on the C++ side via a ZeroMQ `recv` call.

I've tried changing the buffer type on the JavaScript side to UintArray type to see if that changed anything, but to no luck. I'm not sure what else to try.

Is there any way to solve this issue without working in the `npm zeromq` source files (I'm not sure how to do that or if I want to).

Update *** Code Example of message building ***

```
var data = new ProtoData.Data1();
data.setTemp(128); // type is int32
var payload = data.serializeBinary();
var size = payload.length + 4; // 16 bits
var head1 = 4; // 8 bits
var head2 = 4; // 8 bits
var payload_buf = Buffer.from(payload);
// create the header
var header = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
header.writeUInt16LE(size, 0);
header.writeUInt8(head1, 2);
header.writeUInt8(head2, 3);
var msg = Buffer.concat([header, payload_buf]);
zmqPubSock.sock.send(msg);
```

Comment: It seems like you are processing binary data with JavaScript text functions and datatypes. Please show your code.

Comment: @Tom Blodgey done! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you nailed the diagnosis. It looks like an [open issue](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/issues/268) with zeromq.js, and rightly so—a messaging library that doesn't do binary!?!

The issue reporter suggests zeromq-ng instead.

Another alternative is to use Base64.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! I'll look into the alternative